# Phonegap Cordova 5.x looking for working Android QR-Code-Scanner Plugin (Google API 23)

Tags: android, cordova, barcode

i am looking for a working barcode-scanner plugin..
i´ve already found this one: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
..but unfortunately it doesn´t work with the Google API 23 (there are errors occurring by the bookmarkcolumns plugin included).. as far as i know it works with api 22 or less

so the errors ocurr in the CaptureActivity (src folder) > com.google.zxing.client.android.share
files:

```
AppPickerActivity.java
BookmarkPickerActivity.java
ShareActivity.java
Error: BookmarkColumns cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

so my question is, is there any other barcode-scanner-solution for phonegap or is there a way to fix these errors?

any help would be appreciated!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**BarCode Scanner :**

Click on the below link you will find multiple numbers of barcode scanner plugin. Please add which ever shoots your API level.

[Barcode Scanner plugins](http://plugreg.com/search?q=Barcode)